# "irgendwo hinfliegen" oder "irgendwohin fliegen"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, particle

> I think he will fly somewhere next week, but I can't remember where.

Wie übersetzt man das ins Deutsche?

> (a) Ich glaube, er wird nächste Woche **irgendwo hinfliegen**, aber ich kann mich nicht erinnern **wo**.

oder

> (b) Ich glaube, er wird nächste Woche **irgendwohin fliegen**, aber ich kann mich nicht erinnern **wohin**.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Partikel *hin* zu *irgendwo* oder zu *fliegen* gehören sollte.

Comment: Selbst wenn betont werden sollte, dass es sich um den Hinflug (nicht den Rückflug, der selten nach „irgendwo“ geht) handelt, was im konkreten Beispiel nicht der Fall ist, kann nur (b) funktionieren oder evtl. __irgendwohin hinfliegen__. Umgangssprachlich wird _wohin_ auch durch _nach wo_ ersetzt oder das _irgend_ weggelassen.

Comment: @Crissov... ich verstehe die Begründung nicht. Warum kann nur b) funktionieren? Und irgendwohin hinfliegen ist ja wohl klar unidiomatisch. Genauso wie "irgendwohin hingehen"

Comment: http://canoo.net/blog/2013/09/25/irgendwohin-gehen-oder-irgendwo-hingehen/ In diesem Blog-Eintrag wird auf die selbe Thematik eingegangen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beide Sätze sind richtig und "hinfliegen" ist idiomatischer.  Die Version mit "irgendwohin" mag hochsprachlicher sein, aber eine echte Auswahl lässt sich nur treffen, wenn man das Register kennt in dem der Ausgangsatz verwendet wird.

Generell sind "hin" und "her" sehr frei und können entweder an das Fragewort "wo" bzw. das Adverb "da" angehängt werden oder ans Verb. Die Bedeutung ist in beiden Fällen die gleiche. Es ist nicht wichtig, wo es steht. Es ist nur wichtig, dass es da ist.

Wie die anderen Antworten bereits erwähnen hat "hinfliegen" eine zweite Bedeutung. Das tut aber hier nichts zur Sache und nur um Zweifel auszuräumen:

> Wohin gehst/fährst/schwimmst/springst/fliegst du? = Wo gehst/fährst/schwimmst/springst/fliegst du hin?

EDIT:

Da einige anscheinend nicht glauben können, dass "hinfliegen" verwendet wird [hier der Link](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=+%22Wo+*+hinfliegen%22) zur obligatorischen, ganz unwissenschaftlichen Google-Suche. "Wohin * fliegen" hat zum Vergleich 6 Millionen Hits. Beide Versionen sind also etabliert. 
Ich kann auch gerne noch Beispiele aus der Deutschen Literatur raussuchen, wenn es denn sein muss.

Comment: Naja, `==` ist übertrieben, denn die Varianten mit _wohin_ etc. sind gehobener / formaler / schriftsprachlicher – so sehr, dass manche die Alternative als Stilfehler ansehen.

Comment: Zwei mal Downvote... bitte begründen Leute. Ich habe es auch gemacht.

Comment: @Crissov... vielleicht ist == übertrieben aber Stilfehler ist es ebenso. Die Realität hat entschieden (siehe Link im Edit)

Answer (score 4):

*Irgendwo* und *wo* beziehen sich auf einen Ort oder eine Stelle, während *irgendwohin* und *wohin* eine Richtung zu einem Ort oder eine Stelle ausdrücken. Das bedeutet, Satz (b) ist richtig.

Der Satz (a) kann auch richtig sein, wenn mit *hinfliegen* gemeint ist, dass man hinfällt. Natürlich würde der Satz, so wie er da steht keinen Sinn ergeben:

> Ich glaube, er wird nächste Woche irgendwo hinfliegen[=hinfallen], aber ich kann mich nicht erinnern wo.

Letztlich kannst du in Satz (a) auch *von* einfügen, und der Satz ist damit korrekt. Hier müsste der Kontext zuvor aber bereits aufklären, was das Ziel ist, sprich, worauf sich *hinfliegen* bezieht.

> Ich glaube, er wird nächste Woche von irgendwo hinfliegen, aber ich kann mich nicht erinnern von wo.

Comment: "Wenn sie weiter mit diesen Mörderabsätzen rumstelzt, wird sie noch irgendwann irgendwo hinfliegen."

Comment: Ich stimme @Em1 zu, aber der Unterschied ist gering genug, dass die meisten Leute beide Versionen als "mit dem Flugzeug irgendwo hin fliegen" verstehen werden.

Comment: @Robert "hinfliegen" ist ein Wort.

Comment: Beide Sätze sind richtig. Bloss weil Satz a noch eine weitere Bedeutung hat, heißt das nicht, das er nicht funktioniert. Mein Argument: Hinflug. Das Substantiv zum Verb "hinfliegen". -1

Comment: @Emanuel Satz (a) kann gar nicht richtig sein, wegen dem "wo" am Ende.

Comment: @Em1... ich würde dagegen halten, dass das "hin" vom Verb bis dahin "trägt".

Comment: Man könnte überlegen, ob "hinfliegen" auch mit anderen und insb. konkreten Orten verwendet werden kann: "nach Berlin hinfliegen", "auf die Südseeinsel hinfliegen", etc. Zumindestens ich finde diese Wendungen etwas merkwürdig.

Comment: @blutorange... sind sie auch, weil "hin" ja eben genau die generische "Zieladverbiale" ist. Sobald ein Ziel genannt wird braucht man sie nicht. Sprich, das Verb "hinfliegen" lässt sich nicht mit einer Ortsadverbiale verbinden. Das heißt aber nicht, dass es nicht existiert.

Answer (score 0):

b.

"Wo?" is where, but "Wohin?" is where to. As "hinfliegen" can also mean that I fall on the ground, it is easily understood to be a question concerning the location of an accident:

> "Wo bist Du hingeflogen? Ich bin in der Germanistenstraße hingeflogen"

"Wohin" implies some kind of movement to a specific location:

> "Wohin bist Du geflogen/gefahren? In das Germanistenland bin ich geflogen/gefahren."

Comment: This is certainly logical but it's totally not reality. Case in point: Hinflug. The noun exists so why shouldn't the verb. Just because there's a double meaning doesn't make it wrong. -1

Comment: @Emanuel: His question was: how should I translate it and b. is definitely better, I haven't said that a. is wrong. In the end I think it is, as the second **wo** is definitely wrong.

Comment: I disagree that a) is better and I disagree that the "wo" is wrong. Why is it wrong? Why is b) better?

Comment: Emanuel: Simple. "Du bist wo?" asks, at which place I *am*, "Du gehst wo", at which place I go. It inquires location. But the speaker does not want to know *wo* someone will be or does something, but *wohin* he will travel.

Comment: "Ich weiß nicht, wo ich hingehen soll". Hier haben wir "wo" und es geht trotzdem um ein Ziel. Was wichtig ist, ist, dass ein "hin" irgendwo im Satz ist, denn es markiert die "Zielgerichtetheit". In diesem Fall ist ein "hin" im Satz und ich bin der Meinung, dass es bis ans Ende wirkt. Man kommt im Übrigen auch durch eine ganz simple Auslassung zu einem einzelnen "wo" am Ende. "Er ist irgendwo hingegangen, aber ich weiß nicht mehr wo [er hingegangen ist]". Das wo ist wichtig, den Rest kennen wir schon. Daher kann er weggelassen werden.