# Niveau von "wo hingehen" und "wohin gehen"

Tags: usage, particle

> (a) Wo möchtest du hingehen?
>
> (b) Wohin möchtest du gehen?

Wie schon erwähnt in der gewählten Antwort zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/irgendwo-hinfliegen-oder-irgendwohin-fliegen), sind sowohl (a) als auch (b) richtig.

Aber welchen Satz würde man benutzen in formellen Situationen, welchen in der Umgangssprache? In derselben Antwort wird ein bisschen dazu geäußert, aber eine richtige Diskussion darüber gibt es dort nicht.

Comment: Persönlich und rein nach Intuition würde ich meinen, dass (a) informeller, also Umgangssprache ist, während (b) "gehobener" und damit formeller klingt. Da dies nur meine persönliche Präferenz widerspiegelt, nur als Kommentar.

Comment: Es mag meine Privatmeinung sein, aber für mich sind die Fragen auch inhaltlich nicht gleich. a) legt den schwerpunkt auf dem Ort an dem man dann ist, also gehen, um dann irgendwo anders zu sein (in einem Cafe z.B.) bei b) ist der für mich auf dem Gehen, es könnte auch ein Spaziergang sein. Wo kennzeichnet einen Ort, das Ergebnis, wohin eine Richtung, den Prozess. Davon ab, würde ich mich @Teolha anschließen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standardsprachlich korrekt ist hier die Verwendung von Richtungsadverbien *(wohin, woher)* in Verbindung mit einem Bewegungsverb. Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* entspricht diese Ausdrucksweise dem geschriebenen Standarddeutsch.

> Wohin gehst du?
>
> Ich weiß nicht, wohin er gefahren ist.
>
> Woher kommst du?
>
> Woher bist du gekommen?

Allerdings wird heute tatsächlich häufig das Ortsadverb *wo* gebraucht. Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* gehört diese Ausdrucksweise hauptsächlich der gesprochenen Sprache an.

> Wo gehst du hin?
>
> Ich weiß nicht, wo er hingefahren ist.
>
> Wo kommst du her?
>
> Wo bist du hergekommen?

Vermutlich ganz ähnlich ist der Unterschied zwischen dem standardsprachlichen Ausdruck *dahin gehen* und dem umgangssprachlichen Ausdruck *da hingehen*, siehe auch [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18578/9551).