# Gehen oder hingehen

Tags: word-choice

Warum wird der folgende Satz mit "hin" benutzt:

> Ich gehe dorthin.

Folgender aber [üblicherweise?] ohne:

> Ich möchte nach Deutschland gehen.

Soll der Letzte nicht so heißen?

> Ich möchte nach Deutschland **hin**gehen.

Falls beide grammatisch sind, möchte ich wissen welcher eher richtiger ist.

Bitte Antworten auf Deutsch.

Comment: Möglicherweise relevant: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/irgendwo-hinfliegen-oder-irgendwohin-fliegen und https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/hinkommen-sprachgebrauch

Answer (score 4):

Du kannst das Verb *»gehen«* sowohl mit als auch ohne Angabe eines Ziels verwenden:

- Ohne Ziel/Richtung, also an einem festen Ort:

  > Was machst du im Krankenhaus?
  >   **Ich gehe dort** täglich eine Stunde lang in einem Laufstall. Ich hatte einen Schlaganfall und lerne wieder, wie man geht.
  >   *<sup>Ort = ein Laufstall in einem Krankenhaus (Ich bleibe beim Gehen die ganze Zeit in diesem Laufstall und in diesem Krankenhaus, also an einem festen Ort)</sup>*
  >
  > Gestern habe ich einen Betrunkenen dabei beobachtet, wie **er** über den Hauptplatz **gegangen ist.**
  >   *<sup>Ort = der Hauptplatz (Richtung und Ziel sind unbekannt)</sup>*
  >
  > Ich kann mit Ihnen nicht Schritt halten. **Sie gehen** so schnell. Bitte **gehen Sie** langsamer.
  >   *<sup>Richtung und Ziel sind unbekannt, der Angesprochene befindet sich am selben Ort wie der Sprecher</sup>*
- Mit konkretem Ziel oder konkreter Richtung:

  > Ich gehe **ins Krankenhaus.**
  >   *<sup>Ziel = das Krankenhaus</sup>*
  >
  > Der Betrunkene geht **in die Kneipe.**
  >   *<sup>Ziel = die Kneipe</sup>*
  >
  > Herr Müller geht **nach Norden.**
  >   *<sup>Richtung = nach Norden</sup>*

Wenn man nun aber von einer zielgerichteten Bewegung sprechen will, und das Ziel entweder aus dem Kontext bereits bekannt ist, oder wenn das Ziel Gegenstand einer Frage ist, verwendet man das Wort *»hin«*, das sowohl mit dem Fragewort *»wo«* als auch mit dem Verb *»gehen«* als auch mit *»da«* und *»dort«* fest verbunden sein kann:

> Wo**hin** gehst du?
>
> Gestern war ich im neuen Einkaufszentrum. Morgen gehe ich wieder dort**hin.**
>
> Gestern war ich im neuen Einkaufszentrum. Ich werde aber kein zweites Mal **hingehen,** denn dort sind die Preise viel zu hoch.

Man kann also entweder ein bestimmtes Ziel angeben:

> Ich möchte **nach Deutschland** gehen.

Oder man sich auf ein Ziel aus dem Kontext beziehen, ohne es im Satz explizit zu erwähnen:

> Ich habe mich mit Gerda unterhalten. Sie lebt in Deutschland, und ihr gefällt es sehr gut dort. Ich möchte das alles mit eigenen Augen sehen, und daher werde ich auch dort **hin**gehen.

Wenn man aber im Satz bereits ein Ziel oder eine Richtung angibt, ist das Wort *»hin«* nicht nur überflüssig, sondern sogar falsch:

> falsch: <del>Ich möchte nach Deutschland hingehen.</del>

Comment: Auch noch erwähnenswert: *dorthin gehen* ist bedeutungsgleich mit *dort hingehen*.

Comment: Gilt diese Regel auch für andere Bewegungsverben?

Comment: @sermonionx: Ja.

Answer (score 0):

In der Regel bezieht sich »hin« in Verbindung mit »gehen« auf einen bereits bekannten Ort, der entweder schon genannt wurde oder auch [mit dem Finger] angezeigt.

> »Oma steht vor dem Laden und kann nicht alles tragen.« – »Dann geh
> doch hin!«
>
> »Morgen singt Mick Jagger in der Stadthalle! Der lebt noch!« –
> »Dann geh ich hin!«
>
> *(gestreckter Finger)* »Da liegt ein Geldbeutel!« – »Wo?« – »Na da!« – »Dann geh doch hin.«

Es gibt aber durchaus legale Fälle, bei denen »hin« ohne Rückbezug auf eine explizite Ortsangabe auftritt, nämlich einer im gleichen Satz genannten Ortsangabe unmittelbar vorausgeht, was durch einfache Umstellung erreicht wird (»hin zur Kuh gegangen« statt »zur Kuh hingegangen« bzw. »hin zu ihm« statt »zu ihm hin«).

> *(Tagebuch eines Bauern)* Früh aufgestanden, dann hin zur Kuh gegangen.
>
> Du hast dich danebenbenommen? Dann geh gleich hin zu ihm und klär das
> ab.

In beiden Fällen ist »hin« optional.